# How do I get unstuck when I never got the downward or upward thrust?

Tags: zelda-2-the-adventure-of-link

I'm in the Great Palace in *Zelda II: The Adventure of Link*, and I never got the downward or upward thrust. I'm at the part where I have to get past a stack of blocks that I'm on top of, and it seems that's the only way. I tried to go back out but the force field won't let me.

By the way, I am using an emulator and don't mind using cheats, so any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I did some testing on my end and discovered the memory address for thrust is

```
 0x0796
```

Apparently a hex value of 00 (Dec 0 )means that its disabled. And a hex value of 10 (Dec 16 ) means that's it's enabled.

So just use your emulator program to modify the above address to this value and you will be able to downward thrust.

Further testing shows that a hex value of 14 ( Dec 20 ) will enable both downward thrust and upward thrust.

To make this even easier if your emulator supports pro-action replay codes ( most do). The below codes will work.

```
0796-10 - For Downward Thrust Only
0796-14 - For Downward & Upward Thrusts
```